# Who is Tulasidas? What is the story of him?

Tags: ramayana, belief, scripture, rama

Who is Tulasidas? What is the story of him? What did he create except ramcharitmanas and hanuman chalisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great poet Tulsidas Hindu society and the talent-rays not only India but the whole world is illuminated. Very sorry that the time of birth of the poet lying in the darkness of disputes. So far the research findings also appear unable to provide us certainty

The birthplace of Ram Naresh Tripathi concludes that Tulsidas is Soron. The location remains in Soron Tulsidas Tulsidas Nanddas's brother-in-law of the successor Narasimha temple and Tripathi from the existence of the secret of living their successors are not upheld.

Tulsidas in the parents' relationship is not any solid information. According to the materials and evidence was their father's name Atma Ram Dubey. Bvishypuran but his father's name is mentioned Sridhar. Rahim said couplets based on the mother's name is Hulsi.

His guru's name Naraharidāsa

Ramcharitmanas, Vinaya Patrika, "geetawali",Dohavali, sahitya ratna, Hanuman Chalisa, Vairagya Sandipani, Janaki Mangal, Parvati Mangal were some of his works as per materials

[image: Tulsidas statue at Manas Mandir, Chitrakuta, Satna, India.]

Tulsidas statue at Manas Mandir, Chitrakuta, Satna, India.